# How to create product id when your db auto_increment increases by 10?

Tags: auto-increment

I have this weird problem, `Azure MySQL database` increments by 10 instead of 1 every time I insert a row in it.

So the primary key on every table in that database goes like this - `1,11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,101`, and so on.. it was supposed to be `1,2,3,4,5,6,...` etc..

I think it is a database specific problem since I have the same code running on localhost and Azure DB. This problem is only on the Azure DB. So I figured out the problem is with clear DB using this 10 increment as mentioned in:

http://www.cleardb.com/developers/help/faq#general_16

So now basically what I want is to make the url look good, with the product id in the URL increment by 1. How are others solving this problem?

Is it by adding a 1 to the end of the product number that you get from the URL and querying the DB or by creating a new column called product id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change auto-increment step back to 1 using:

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
```

I would not do it however - it may screw up your Azure/ClearDB installation if you are using replication.

In general, you should not be fixed up on how exactly primary keys are allocated. Even with `auto_increment_increment=1` there is no 100% guarantee that keys will be allocated without any gaps - typical reason for gaps are aborted transactions.

Comment: hmm. So if I want to store product ID, do I store that in a separate column? Is that not kind of redundant?

Comment: @EchoAlex: Your comment does not seem to relate to question you asked. If you want to store something in one column or another, that's your choice. But this has nothing to do with resetting auto-increment delta, which I provided an answer for.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It makes sense, but then I dont want to mess up with clearDB installation. So the work around I found now is t o add a separate column for the product id in the format I want. Thanks for the help :)